# get email data from Gmail on the base of UID

Tags: php, mysql, email, gmail, imap

I want to fetch emails detail from my gmail account and save into Mysql Table. I wan to Fetch emails on the base of UID. But I am not getting the required results. Can anyone tell me how I can fetch Email, Subject, Body of the email when a new email arrives on my gmail account. Here is my code :

```
/* connect to server */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'myemail';
$password = 'mypassword';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password,OP_READONLY) or die('Cannot connect to Tiriyo: ' . imap_last_error());
//echo $inbox;
/* grab emails */
//$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
$latest_uid = 16; // Last UID inserted in my table 

$emails   = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL', SE_UID);
print_r($emails);
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

  /* begin output var */
  $output = '';

  /* put the newest emails on top */
  rsort($emails);

  /* for every email... */
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    //$email_number=$emails[0];
//print_r($emails);
    /* get information specific to this email */
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 1);
    //echo $message;
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,"1:{$email_number}");
   // $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

    /* output the email header information */
   // $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview->from.'</span>';


     $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview->uid.'</span>';

    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
  }

  echo $output;
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

I am getting error :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\imap\custom\index2.php on line 37

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\imap\custom\index2.php on line 38

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\imap\custom\index2.php on line 41
```

this is line 37:

```
$output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview->subject.'</span> ';
```

Comment: which is line 37?

Comment: see the edit question

Comment: did you try this $emails   = imap_search($inbox, 'NEW ');
i hope it helps you better. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try This code :

```
$mbox = imap_open("Hostname", "username", "password")
     or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);

// Fetch an overview for all messages in INBOX
$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
foreach ($result as $overview) {
    echo "#{$overview->msgno} ({$overview->date}) - From: {$overview->from}
    {$overview->subject}\n";
}
imap_close($mbox);
```

Let me know result.

Comment: it is fetching all the emails

Comment: do you have a need to a specific user?

Comment: No, I want to fetch only new emails

Answer (score 0):

i have one link for you it helps you

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php

there is all type of conditions and filters link available

> ```
> ALL - return all messages matching the rest of the criteria
> ANSWERED - match messages with the \\ANSWERED flag set
> BCC "string" - match messages with "string" in the Bcc: field
> BEFORE "date" - match messages with Date: before "date"
> BODY "string" - match messages with "string" in the body of the message
> CC "string" - match messages with "string" in the Cc: field
> DELETED - match deleted messages
> FLAGGED - match messages with the \\FLAGGED (sometimes referred to as Important or Urgent) flag set
> FROM "string" - match messages with "string" in the From: field
> KEYWORD "string" - match messages with "string" as a keyword
> NEW - match new messages
> OLD - match old messages
> ON "date" - match messages with Date: matching "date"
> RECENT - match messages with the \\RECENT flag set
> SEEN - match messages that have been read (the \\SEEN flag is set)
> SINCE "date" - match messages with Date: after "date"
> SUBJECT "string" - match messages with "string" in the Subject:
> TEXT "string" - match messages with text "string"
> TO "string" - match messages with "string" in the To:
> UNANSWERED - match messages that have not been answered
> UNDELETED - match messages that are not deleted
> UNFLAGGED - match messages that are not flagged
> UNKEYWORD "string" - match messages that do not have the keyword "string"
> UNSEEN - match messages which have not been read yet
> ```

```
$s_Date = "20 January 2018";
$b_Date = "10 December 2018"; 
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SINCE "'.$s_Date.'" BEFORE"'.$b_Date.'"' );
```

now you can do your desire you need to some changes

like below :-

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'NEW');
```